# Can I use a Mac mini without the power brick?

Tags: mac, mac-mini, power, power-management

I don't have the power brick for my Mac mini with me but I have cord that plugs into the back of it, can I use it without and plug directly into the wall? Any harm?

The model is A1347

Comment: It's really pretty simple: did it come with a power brick? If yes then you can't use it without the brick. And this applies to **any** electronic device that comes with a power brick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's a 2005-2009 model then NO! You absolutely cannot plug directly from a AC power source to a computer that does not have a built in transformer power supply, which the Mac mini 2005-2009 model does not have.  The AC current must be converted to DC current first and that is what the Mac mini's power supply does.

Starting in 2010 the Mac mini used a built-in power supply and the power cord does not use a power brick like in previous modles, it plugs directly from wall to computer.

[image: Mac mini Mid 2010 Model A1347 Contents of Box]
[image: Model A1347 Built-in Power Supply]

Comment: The model is mc816ll/a , does that require a brick?

Comment: @zm15, I've edited my answer to reflect more accurately the need for the power supply with a power brick.

Comment: Based on a google search, mc816ll/a is the 2011 model. In general, a model that requires a power brick would not be expected to have an IEC inlet at the back that would allow an AC cord to be plugged in to it.

Comment: @user3439894 Just to make sure, does the back of your mac mini look like this image? https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/macmini/mac_mini_mid11_ports.png

Comment: @Random832, I'm not the one asking the question about the Mac min's power supply, zm15 is.  All Mac mini's starting with 2010 models going forward use a built-in power supply and thus a straight power cord from wall (or AC power source) to the Mac Mini's built-in power supply.

Comment: er sorry @zm15 please check if your mac's power inlet looks like the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you want it to go Bang & never work again.

The plug design ought to be such that you cannot even do it.

Comment: True, I have another plug that happens to fit the back of the mini, and didn't know if it would cause damage.

Comment: not enough information to vaguely guess - but think of it this way… Wall socket 110 - 240v - power brick transformer down to maybe 12v. ...does random spare cable do the same task?